# How can I configure autocomplete for project in Brackets?

Tags: autocomplete, adobe-brackets, ternjs

I'm using Brackets for development applications on the Node.JS. As I know Brackets relies on the TernJS library. When I add the root of the project file named `.tern-project` with the following lines, I do not see any change in the autocomplete.

```
{
  "libs": [],
  "plugins": {
    "node": {}
  }
}
```

After that I still see hints for browser, JQuery hints, AngularJS hints, etc. How can I configure TernJS for project(directory) in Brackets?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [ternific](https://github.com/MiguelCastillo/Brackets-Ternific) plugin to work pretty well for per project tern configuration.